# Dynamic tables and models in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have the next tables:

```
pages
    id
    title
    ...

dynamic_table_1_infos
    id
    page_id
    image_id
    dynamic_field_1
    dynamic_field_2
    ...

dynamic_table_2_infos
...
```

So there are "one to many" relationships.

Is there any way to use a general approach without creating a DynamicTable[No]Info model "on the fly" for each table?

And what if I will need some extra methods in these models?

The "Page" model will have many relationships with "dynamic_table_[no]_infos" tables. So I will probably need a general method for doing this.
(Has many dynamic_table_1_infos / has many dynamic_table_2_infos ...)

What I am trying to do is somehow inspired by Dupal`s content types.

Comment: What I do when I'm not sure of the structure of the data, is store it all as JSON. This could solve your problem. This is great in Laravel or PHP because you can then parse the JSON back as objects. However, I'm pretty sure that it's bad practice.

Anyway, you could create an overall `dynamic_info` table and then just have columns, `id`, `page_id`, and then finally, a `data` column, in which you could store your dynamic data as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a single model data to multiple tables depending on the value of some model attribute, you'll need to override model's **getTable()** method to return the name of the table it should write to.

I'm not sure how you want to decide to which table Eloquent should save to - for example, if you had an attribute called **segment** in your mode, you could just do:

```
public function getTable() {
  return 'dynamic_table_' . $this->segment . '_infos';
}
```

Comment: A dynamic model could have for example an image_id (also dynamic added). The model will be created "on the fly" and I will need to add relationships in it "on the fly" to not manually edit it. ("image id" belongs to "Image" model).

Comment: I have no idea what you need. Could you post some more examples? And tell me WHY you'd need such a non-standard behaviour?

Comment: What I want to build is somehow inspired by Drupal`s content types. In my case each content type has a custom table (article with x fields / product with y fields etc.). Manually is easy but I would like to have an admin interface for it. So when I add a content type I can create dynamic_table_1_infos, 2, 3 etc. I can create even the models with Artisan command but I do not know how to do the relationships. A dynamic table could have an image reference from images table for example.