# How to create models for dynamically generated tables (on the fly)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I stumbled upon this problem today. My project has a few tables, for which I have created their dedicated Models. However, my project allows user to create dynamic tables.

How do I create relationships or models for/between these dynamically generated tables?

Comment: Could you let us know what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. A web search pulls up quite a few relevant-looking hits... For example, does [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158881/dynamic-tables-and-models-in-laravel-5) help at all?

Comment: For now I'm able to create dynamic tables during run-time. That's not a big thing. I was just curious to know If I can create Eloquent models between these tables. 

If there is no such way, then I'll use raw queries to fetch my data. I looked at these links, they don't help much. However, 1 of the comments in the above link, to store things in JSON is okay. I'm already doing it.

Comment: @VishalSh, instead of using Eloquent models use directly the Query Builder. You will be using almost the same syntax as with Eloquent model, but... without model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend to create Eloquent Models on dynamically generated tables, because Eloquent Models are here to help developers with already created database tables (features like relationships, scopes, attributes casting are usually defined for existing database tables).

What would be my recommendation? Use the [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) instead. You will have almost the same functionalities of Eloquent Models, except without model.

Instead of having something like:

```php
DynTable::where('foo', 123)
        ->where('bar', 456)
        ->first();
```

You will have the following:

```php
DB::table('dyn_table')
  ->where('foo', 123)
  ->where('bar', 456)
  ->first();
```

Basically, the same. But, with the benefit that you can specify any table name to the Query Builder, but you can't change the table name to an Eloquent Model (in a running script).

Comment: Yeah, thats the only way left now. I had the same thought. Just wanted someone experienced to comment on their approach. Accepting this as answer

Comment: I'm not the most experienced, but that's the only way that makes sense to me right now. :)